# How to make view grow outside of screen

Tags: android, xml, view

How can i make a view, or something that looks like has part of it outside of the screen boundaries?

I want to give the impression that the view continues after the screen

I want to make something like this:

[image: what i want]

but the maximum i could get was:

[image: what i got]

I already tried using an image, but i doesn't meet what I need.

could someone please help me?

Comment: Thanks @Dave for the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achieve this (using `ConstraintLayout`) as follows:

**Code (to be added in your build.gradle (Module:app) file):**

```
dependencies {
    // For ConstraintLayout:
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

    // For CircleImageView:
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
}
```

**XML Code (for the layout file):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/civCircle"
        android:layout_width="720dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:src="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Screenshot (of the above code):**

*For screen size - 7.0 inch (1200 x 1920 pixels) [Device: Nexus 7]*

[image]

I hope, this helps you. Furthermore, it would be awesome for you if you could find some library that draws an oval-shaped view for you (as the view shown above in the screenshot is circular).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, I just found out this library for drawing the Oval and many other shapes as a matter of fact.https://github.com/gleb8k/Android-PathShapeView

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer. Nice, good for you. I hope, now your UI looks perfect.  ;-)